# UseEllipses DW Property in PB 10.5

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to use the UseEllipses DW property in PB 10.5. I found that this property is used in PB 11 and after but I don't know if you know something more for this in PB 10.5 or another way to implement it...
I 've tried this => dw_master.Modify("comments.EditMask.UseEllipsis=Yes") but an error message is shown that 'UseEllipses' is an unknown property...

That's why Iam asking you if you know another way of this property, in order to use it in PB 10.5.2

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

No, this is [a new feature in PowerBuilder 11.0](http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/New_in_PowerBuilder_11/PB11New_-_DataWindow_Features/PB11New_-_UseEllipsis_DataWind/pb11new_-_useellipsis_datawind.html), so there's nothing you can do in 10.5 to make this feature work.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated something like this a long time ago in PB 8 using overlaid fields, SetPosition (I think; might have been dot notation & SendToBack), and manual focus control.  It's a *lot* of work and doesn't perform real well. I'm pretty sure I don't have the code any more.

Do you not have the option of using PB 11 or 12?